# validation of only alphabet and underscore in my tablename using sas macro

Tags: validation, sas, sas-macro

> =====================================================================
> I want to validate (sanity check) for my table name that only contains alphabets and underscore . If anything else then raise an error and when error arise it abort or proceed accordingling.
> ==========================================================================
> What to create a macro using if else condition.
> If anything else then raise an error and when error arise it abort or proceed accordingly.
> Example- Fsc_bank, bank,
> if bank1, blank or alphanumeric, numeric then produce error.
> What to create a macro using if else condition.

[image contains code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntXjM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify this to use regex instead: `/^[a-z0-9_]*$/i`

```
%macro check_table(table_name);   
    %if(&table_name. =) %then %do;
        %put ERROR: Table name cannot be empty.;
        %return;
    %end;

    %if(%sysfunc(prxmatch(/^[a-z0-9_]*$/i, &table_name)))
        %then %put The table name %upcase(&table_name) is valid.;
    %else %put ERROR: Table name can only contain letters and underscores.;
%mend;
```

Test:

`%check_table(foo);`

```
The table name FOO is valid.
```

`%check_table(foo!);`

```
ERROR: Table name can only contain letters and underscores.
```

`%check_table;`

```
ERROR: Table name cannot be empty.
```

Comment: I want loop also for my tablename and I am calling this macro in my main code and we need to return a value as well in that which we can check in main code and accordingly proceed or abort running.

Comment: Please create a new question that asks how to do this, and post your code you have tried as text. Your current question does not ask this. This answer covers only what you have asked.